# Silex + Ajax + SEO

Tags: php, ajax, seo, silex

What is the best way to go if you want to implement SEO friendly single page ajax website with Silex?

I would like to use routes (no hardcoded urls) and to support back button (browser history) with hashbangs or HTML5 pushState.

I guess it can be done for example with combination of [JavascriptRoutingServiceProvider](https://github.com/RafalFilipek/JavascriptRoutingServiceProvider) and [pathjs](https://github.com/mtrpcic/pathjs) or something similar. But I guess someone already solved this problem, so I'm interested to hear your experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I fixed it.

If javascript is enabled I'm preventing main menu links default behavior and [sending ajax requests instead](https://github.com/umpirsky/Silex-Kitchen-Edition/blob/1df5acccd6e3305c2354e1d81d8c90e98f3f18a1/resources/assets/js/script.js). When request is finished I'm keeping browser history with `window.history.pushState()`.

I made [layout](https://github.com/umpirsky/Silex-Kitchen-Edition/blob/1df5acccd6e3305c2354e1d81d8c90e98f3f18a1/views/layout.html.twig) conditional. I'm loading content with header and footer if it is a full page refresh (bot or javascript disabled) or main content if it is ajax request.

This way, I have consistent behavior with or without javascript enabled, but using ajax instead full page refresh. And most important is that I keep Silex routing.

Feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I will focus on SEO friendly part.

You can use as much "fancy stuff" as you can in your website, if you and your site visitors don't have any problem with that.

**But remember the more you add "fancy stuff" the more google and other search engines will push you away from themselves.**

Keeping in mind that there is no sure shot way. I will tell you what you should do.

1. Register with ["Google Webmasters Tools"](http://www.google.com/webmasters/) and use it, specially "Fetch as googlebot" it will tell you the problems and errors while reading(crawling) your website.
2. While developing site, use a firefox addon ["User agent switcher"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/?src=search) it will tell you how your page look like when google see your page.
3. Test your pages with js and css turned off, that's how google and other search engines see your page.

If using those methods you find problems and errors, and find that google is getting a hard time in reading your pages and website than it's an alarm for you to cut down some "fancy stuff" from your website.

There are a ton of other things related to SEO but those above will get you started and put you on the right track to make your website readable, crawlable, indexable for search engines.

Comment: Thanks. I know that, and there is more info about making ajax website crawlable on https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/. Of course you must provide full page snapshots if javascript is disabled. BTW, you say css turned off, are you sure that search engines are not parsing css? Because if that is true, you can put hidden content to boost SEO. Thanks for you answer again.

Comment: of course they parse CSS but not for doing the presenting and delivering of that page to your visitors that's the job of your browser. The point of turning css off is it's how the "googlebot the software" see your page content.

Comment: e.g. if you put some content in footer and use css to display that in header. Your site visitors will see that in header but googlebot despite knowing that you have used css to display it in header will see it in footer.

Comment: But what if you hide it? Google bot will see it, but will google evaluate that content when ranking your page?

Comment: actually bot will see it, evaluate it, and in most cases will index it as long as you are not trying to trick google like "keyword stuffing". the question is often asked if your content is important and you want google to index it for search results why do you wanna hide it from users (are you trying to trick google)

Comment: I don't, I'm just curious. Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 1):

I whole heartedly concur with Metadice above. One should be very practical with items placed on websites as there are so many gimmicks to aid this and that along with SEO products.  We can sometimes think we are being too clever as though the people that work for the likes of Google are not as bright as we are!  Yeah right!

I go by a basic ruling.  I must have one priority and that is to have the most up to date, relevant content on my site and plenty of it.  To fulfil the searchers needs.  Everything else is secondary.  In other words 1 page of content and 10 plugins just ain’t going to cut it…

I have a whole article based on the fact that Google cares little for helping you flaunt your wears and tears… All they wish to do is marry up the most pinned point and relevant content to search term… Full Stop.

To see a more detailed write up please feel free to visit my article post:

http://howtobecomeamillionaires.org/index.php/seo-website/